# gridview clicking effect

Tags: android, gridview, onclick

I have a gridview

```
<GridView
    android:id="@+id/gridview"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="60px"
    android:layout_marginRight="60px"
    android:background="#343434"
    android:listSelector="#00343434"
    android:numColumns="2"
    android:verticalSpacing="25px" >
</GridView>
```

When i click, a grey color box will indicate the item being clicked.

I want to remove the grey color box effect when click an item.

Please give some suggestion, thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

change you line `android:listSelector="#00343434"`

with this line

```
android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
```

Or with

```
android:listSelector="#00000000"
```

Comment: @AlanLai show me what you have tried. did you manipulate it in code too like setSelector("#somecolor")??

Answer (score 1):

When u want to set perticular Image

```
View savedView    ;
gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {


                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


                        v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bgcalendarbox_highlighted);
                            if(savedView==null)
                            {
                                savedView = v;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                savedView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bgcalendarbox);
                                savedView = v;
                            }


                }
            });
```

Othervise

```
android:listSelector="#00000000"
```

Comment: Hi,can you pls help.. I have a grid view with image as a single item in grid When I m clicking in space left around image ,I get touch feedback from gridview but no feedback on clicking on the image.. what can I do? thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
android:listSelector="#00000000"
```

Add this in your GridView tag.